# Error during installation of sulu-demo

Tags: php, symfony, sulu

I try to install sulu.io demo website and i got an 407 error after executing app:install command.

```
    Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://127.0.0.1:9200/sulu_ro
cks_articles from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.
```

I do not understand why i got this error. I am behind a proxy but it's a local url.

Elasticsearch is correctly accesible via the url http://127.0.0.1:9200

Comment: Can you test if you can access the elasticsearch with curl on the same machine your webserver is running: `curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices\?v`

Comment: Same issue, but it works in my browser

Comment: seems like the webserver is not running on the same machine as your browser. so 127.0.0.1 will not be the correct IP address for elasticsearch for the webserver try your real IP address instead.

Comment: Same issue with my local ip. Curl does not work, but a simple ping works correctly.

Comment: Not sure but I think you need to bind elasticsearch to a specific IP address that its accessable from outside else it will only listen to request from its local machine.  "network.host: 0.0.0.0" should allow that all IPs can access the elasticsearch.